# FBLoginView several call of loginViewShowingLoggedInUser

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I have 2 FBLoginView in 2 differents UIViewController : StartViewController and ProfilViewController.

When I login in the StartViewController, only the delegate method `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` in this controller is called. So it's ok

But when i don't login in the StartView, and i login later in the ProfilView, both method `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` are called : the one in StartViewController and the other one in ProfilViewController

In StartViewController :

```
- (void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
   NSLog(@"start");
}
```

In ProfilViewController :

```
- (void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
   NSLog(@"profile");
}
```

And when i loggin in ProfilViewController both methods are called and i have in console : start profile

How can i just called the method in the controller where i login and not in the others?

Thx a lot.

Comment: Can you put some code? The call in StartView for example.

Comment: ok i did but there isn't a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have the same issue and my solution was to have only one instance of the FBLoginView in the application, store it in singleton class like SSUtils or somewhere else from where you can obtain it later. After that you can place it on the view of the desired controller (in your case StartViewController or ProfilViewController) programmatically and don't forget to set a correct delegate.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the instance as a property in appdelegate and init it in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Wherever you want just refer to the appdelegate's instance and subview it, set delegate to self. In dealloc set delegate to nil and remove from superview. Don't release it.